# Parsing xml inside the CDATA tag (Android)

Tags: android, xml, sax, cdata

I have a question about parsing xml inside a cdata tag inside another xml. I have searched, but I didn't found my exact problem. I post the example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <S:Body>
    <ns2:CSResponse xmlns:ns2="http://webservices....../">
      <RespuestaVentaPrepagoTituloCS1>
        <ICallId>0</ICallId>
        <IResultCode>1</IResultCode>
        <SResulXML>
        <![CDATA[null<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
          <SS_prepagoCS version="0.1" fecha="2013-11-02T06:24:42" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=".\SS_Pasdsd">
            <TTPSearchResult value="1" desc="OK">
              <TTPData xsi:nil="false">
                <SerialNumber>56676543243234</SerialNumber>
                ....
```

But the response that I received is the next:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <S:Body>
    <ns2:CS1Response xmlns:ns2="http://webservices..../">
      <RespuestaVentaPrepagoTituloCS1>
        <ICallId>0</ICallId>
        <IResultCode>1</IResultCode>
        <SResulXML>null&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>&lt;SS_prepagoCS version="0.1" fecha="2013-11-13T10:12:20" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=".\SS_PrepagoCS_v0.1.xsd">  &lt;TTPSearchResult value="1" desc="OK">    &lt;TTPData xsi:nil="false">
```

And I cant parse the content of the cdata because the sax parser cant find the xml tags. Can somebody help me?

Thanks

**EDIT: added more code**

I make the request:

```
    String data = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> " + 
             "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:web=\"http://webservices.sayp.bit.crtm/\"> " + 
             "   <soapenv:Header/> " + 
             "   <soapenv:Body> " + 
             ".... ";

    String action = "";
    HttpResponse res = sendRequest(serverV2 + method, data, action);

    if (res.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
        HttpEntity entity = res.getEntity();
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
        CSHandler handler = new CSHandler();


        parser.parse(entity.getContent()), handler);//entity.getContent
        return handler.getResponse();
    }
```

In some place, I read that changing the entity.getContent() for the next code should work, but the result is the same.

```
        HttpEntity entity = res.getEntity();
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
        CSHandler handler = new CSHandler();
        String xml=EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            Log.i("XML", xml);
        parser.parse(new InputSource(new String(xml)), handler);//entity.getContent
        return handler.getResponse();
        }
```

And the CSHandler is a normal SAX parser that search the tags, but it cant find the tags because the xml is converted to html...

Answer (score 2):

The text in the CDATA section or the escaped text in the other form is likely the same, but cannot be recognized as XML by the parser because of the escaping or wrapping.

What you'll have to do is use your main parser to get all this text into a string, and then start a separate parse for the XML within that string after stripping off at least the "null" at the beginning of it.

If you post Java code showing how you're currently parsing the rest of the xml, we may be able to provide more detailed guidance on handling this.

Comment: @Don Roby It will be be very heplful if you provide some explanation/guidance to parse CDATA. Thanks!